# Prove X and Y both have binomial distributions

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent, non-negative integer-valued, random variables and the distribution has the property
$$
\Pr \{X=x|X+Y=x+y\}=\frac{{m \choose x}{n \choose y}}{{m+n \choose x+y}}
$$
for all non-negative integers $x$ and $y$. Assume that $\Pr\{X=0\}$ and $\Pr\{Y=0\}$ are strictly positive. Show that both $X$ and $Y$ have binomial distributions with the same parameter $p$ and the other parameters being $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please edit your question to include more context, your thoughts on the problem and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $\mathbb{P}(X = x) > 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y = y) > 0$ for any $x \in \{0, \cdots, m\}$ and $y \in \{0, \cdots, n\}$. By the independence of $X$ and $Y$, we can rearrange the equation to

$$ \frac{1}{\binom{m}{x}\binom{n}{y}} \mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)
= \frac{1}{\binom{m+n}{x+y}}\mathbb{P}(X+Y=x+y). \tag{*}$$

Write $p_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X = x)$ and $p_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y = y)$ for simplicity. Then by noting that the right-hand side of $\text{(*)}$ depends only on the sum $x+y$, for $0 \leq x \leq m-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq n-1$,

$$ \frac{1}{\binom{m}{x}\binom{n}{y+1}}p_X(x)p_Y(y+1)
= \frac{1}{\binom{m}{x+1}\binom{n}{y}}p_X(x+1)p_Y(y). $$

Rearranging,

$$ \frac{\binom{m}{x}p_X(x+1)}{\binom{m}{x+1}p_X(x)}
= \frac{\binom{n}{y}p_Y(y+1)}{\binom{n}{y+1}p_Y(y)}. $$

Since this is true for any $x \in \{0,\cdots,m-1\}$ and $y\in\{0,\cdots,n-1\}$, it follows that all these quantities has the same value, which we denote by $c$. Then

$$ \frac{p_X(x+1)}{\binom{m}{x+1}} = c\frac{p_X(x)}{\binom{m}{x}} = \cdots = c^{x+1}p_X(0), \qquad  \frac{p_Y(y+1)}{\binom{n}{y+1}} = c\frac{p_Y(y)}{\binom{n}{y}} = \cdots = c^{y+1}p_Y(0) $$

(You may recognize this as a discrete version of the separation of variables technique.) From this, it is easy to conclude that, for some $p$, $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(m, p)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, p)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clean and nice answer.